# Android deploy settings file not found, not building an APK

Tags: android, qt, qmake

I've encountered this error the second time today. For a while I'm able to build an APK (then I switch to dektop kit, then I switch back), and now I'm unable to build with this error:

Android deploy settings file not found, not building an APK.

first time I solved this by deleting the projectroot/android directory, deleting .user file and recreating those.

eventually it got broken again

now I switched from 5.14.1 to 5.12.7, it solved the issue, maybe temporarily, we'll see...

so my question is what that error message means, which file is the deploy settings file, which process puts it there, and which process deletes it and why?

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: `Binary file Tools/QtCreator/share/qtcreator/translations/qtcreator_ru.qm
matches
Binary file Tools/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator/plugins/libAndroid.so matches`

I'm on linux

Answer (score 4):

Restarting Qt Creator solved this issue for me